# 3D solids of constant width from platonic solids

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry

If you take any of the platonic solids. Take a random corner, don't worry they're all the same, and make this the center of a sphere, where the radius is the distance from your chosen corner to the farthest corner from it. So on a cube the radius would be $\sqrt3\phantom.\cdot\phantom.${sidelength}. Do this for all the corners. The part where all the spheres overlap is a solid of constant width.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, you are not!

More specifically, what you're talking about is a generalization of the so-called *Reuleaux triangle*, and in the simplest case — namely, the one where the solid is a tetrahedron — the resulting surface isn't constant-width; the problem is that an edge-to-edge span can be greater than the distance to a vertex.  For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_tetrahedron .

Comment: For the other platonic solids the situation is worse. Unlike the tetrahedron, now each vertex is opposite another vertex, so you will get curved surfaces opposite each other. While a vertex has constant distance to the opposite curved face, any point in the curved surface around the vertex does not.